# Windows Task Scheduler -- Fails to run Powershell Scripts

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have written two powershell scripts that I need to run every morning. The first generates a text file of the names and location of all of the new files added to a directory within the last twenty-four hours. The second script that I wrote takes that .txt file and e-mails it to myself.

Both of these scripts run perfectly when executed manually. I added them both to the task scheduler but the scheduler does not properly execute the scripts. The text file does not get generated, and the e-mail does not get sent.

Things that I have done (for both scripts):

1. Selected the option to run whether user is logged on or not.
2. Set to run with the highest privleges
3. Have checked and rechecked that my `ExecutionPolicy` is `Unrestricted`.

[image: Here is a picture of the task scheduler at the moment]

Edit: Since that picture is so small here is a direct link: [http://imgur.com/EX7Vxj7](https://imgur.com/EX7Vxj7)

Comment: Under the Actions tab, can you show the action and also the Edit... details for that action?

Comment: Did you include the `-noexit` flag in the arguments for powershell.exe?

Comment: Sure! Here's the actions tab: http://imgur.com/yfTMGLx and here is the edit tab: http://imgur.com/6RwY96w

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm not sure what you're referring to -- would you mind expanding on the -noexit flag?

Comment: In the "Add arguments (optional)" box. When you execute `powershell.exe script.ps1`, it runs the script. When you execute `powershell -noexit script.ps1`, it runs the script but doesn't exit the process afterwards. That doesn't seem to be the case though

Comment: Hmmm...any other thoughts?

Comment: Not good to post links of pictures as part of your question. Please copy and paste the exact `Program/script` text, the `Add arguments (optional)` text, and the `Start in (optional)` text from the task scheduler into your question. Indent them four spaces so we can see the exact strings you are using.

Comment: Use a .bat file to launch Powershell, and redirect it's output to a txt file.  Run it, and then check the txt file for errors.

Answer (score 1):

The Action needs to be set to "Start a program" and the program should be `PowerShell.exe`

Secondly in the Add Arguments box you need to enter `-File '[script path]'`. You can add `-NoExit` if you want to keep the window open afterwards but it will need to be running as your own user of course.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is located on a shared map you need to provide unc to the file like this:

```
\\servername\script.ps1
```

You can find more details in this post:
https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/how-to-schedule-a-powershell-script/